# Java - Reading all strings from a list in .YML

Tags: java, yaml

I was wondering whether it would be possible to read, from a YAML file, and get all the items into a list: It's pretty hard to explain, but i'll provide an example.
ArrayList lists = ???:
will provide all the strings inside of a YAML file which has inside

```
players:
  Y: 0
  X: 8
  Z: 0
```

etc.

Is there specific code to actually get just the strings, so example 
lists would equal to Y, X and Z, as strings and be modifiable.

Really appreciate help on this one :)
Thanks!

Comment: do you want to get the key X,Y,Z or the value of x, y and z?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the interest, I got it though, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any yaml parser. For example [JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/index.html). The yaml in the question is basicaly a Map with key "players" and value another map. So using JYaml you could do like `Object object = Yaml.load(new File("data.yml"));`. By default, JYaml converts a sequence to java.util.ArrayList and a mapping to java.util.HashMap. So we could do like

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> object = (HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>) Yaml.load(new File("data.yml"));
```

and get the key or values like

```
object.get("players").keySet(); // Y, X, Z
object.get("players").values(); // 8, 0, 0
```